# converting float image to int64 and use it in FreeImage

Tags: c++, freeimage

I have a raw 64bit Float binary file, and would like to use FreeImage to tonemapp it. What I have read in the docs that it has that function FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBits So first I should convert it to FreeImage Type from memory, but that function doesn't support 64Bit float images..? Then after that I should tonemap it.. What's the correct approach to tonemap a raw 64bit float ?

Docs is here: https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/exherbo/FreeImage3170.pdf

What I get is a scannled lined distored image
Here is the input file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/ffv6qzvpg05xaja/15_init_image.bin/file

[image]
Here is my attempt ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "FreeImage.h"

int main()
{

    std::ifstream stream("c:/output/15_init_image.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<uint8_t> contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    int width = 2048; // get the width of the image ;
    int height = 3096; // get the height of the image ;
    int bpp = 32;
    FreeImage_Initialise();
    int pitch = 512;

    FIBITMAP* src = FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBitsEx(true, contents.data(), FIT_BITMAP, width, height, pitch, FI_RGBA_RED_MASK,
        FI_RGBA_GREEN_MASK, FI_RGBA_BLUE_MASK, FALSE);
    FreeImage_Save(FIF_JPEG, src, "viewport.jpeg");

    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: When I read the documentation I found that `FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBitsEx()` method takes an `unsigned bpp` argument after the `pitch` argument.. have you tried that overload ? cause that was written there _"The bpp parameter tells FreeImage what the bit depth of the bitmap is"_

Comment: @SujoyGhosh I have tried it, still I get scanned line image, actually now I get 0 bytes image

Comment: Use a hex viewer to view the file and look for patterns.  You'll easily see it is little-endian with 4 bytes per pixel (bpp=32), 8 bits per channel so probably BGRA (not float).  Repeats show width=2048, dividing the file size by the width produces height=3096.

Comment: @HansPassant still a scanned line image, I will update the post with the result and updated code

Comment: @andre_lamothe how sure are you with your raw image file ? have you opened or view it, cause I was not able to view it with any means.

Comment: @SujoyGhosh It's a binary file. You need a hex editor

Comment: @andre_lamothe That much I know but I was just asking if the .bin file has some issues cause I tried some ways converting it to bitmap file but was not able to view the bitmap.

Comment: @SujoyGhosh It has no issues, it's a bunch of bytes, that has pixels information.